# Ruby / Rails meta programing, how to define instance and class methods dynamically?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, metaprogramming

I am trying to make my life simpler inside of a large production Rails 6.0 website. I have a bunch of data that I serve from Redis as denormalized hashes, because Rails, with all the includes and associations is very very slow.

To keep things DRY, I'd like to use a Concern (or module) that can be included within `ApplicationRecord` that allows me to dynamically define the collection methods for the data I want to store.

This is what I have so far:

```
class ApplicationRecord < ActiveRecord::Base
    include DenormalizableCollection
    # ...
end
```

```
# The model
class News < ApplicationRecord
    denormalizable_collection :most_popular
    # ...
end
```

```
# The Concern
module DenormalizableCollection
  extend ActiveSupport::Concern

  class_methods do
    def denormalizable_collection(*actions)
      actions.each do |action|

        # define News.most_popular
        define_singleton_method "#{action}" do
          collection = Redis.current.get(send("#{action}_key"))

          return [] unless collection.present?

          JSON.parse(collection).map { |h| DenormalizedHash.new(h) }
        end

        # define News.set_most_popular
        define_singleton_method "set_#{action}" do
          Redis.current.set(send("#{action}_key"), send("#{action}_data").to_json)
        end

        # define News.most_popular_data, which is a method that returns an array of hashes
        define_singleton_method "#{action}_data" do
          raise NotImplementedError, "#{action}_data is required"
        end

        # define News.most_popular_key, the index key to use inside of redis
        define_singleton_method "#{action}_key" do
          "#{name.underscore}_#{action}".to_sym
        end
      end
    end
  end
end
```

This works, but I doesn't seems right because I cannot also define instance methods, or ActiveRecord `after_commit` callbacks to update the collection inside of Redis.

I'd like to add something like the following to it:

```
    after_commit :set_#{action}
    after_destroy :set_#{action}
```

But obviously these callbacks require an instance method, and `after_commit :"self.class.set_most_popular"` causes an error to be thrown. So I had wanted to add an instance method like the following:

```
class News
   # ...
   def reset_most_popular
       self.class.send("set_most_popular")
   end
end
```

I have been reading as many articles as I can and going through the Rails source to see what I'm missing - as I know I'm defo missing something!

Comment: `define_method` will define instance methods in the same manner that `define_singleton_method` will define class methods.

Comment: you can use the `included` block to define callbacks, and `defined_method` to define instance methods https://api.rubyonrails.org/classes/ActiveSupport/Concern.html

Comment: Do you mean call `define_method` from the `class_methods` block?

Comment: `class_methods` really does something like `ClassMethods = Module.new do ... end` under the covers. So when you call `define_singleton_method` you are defining a singleton method of the module and not the class that is extended by the module. Its like calling `def self.foo` inside a module.

Comment: @max, I would prefer to not use `define_singleton_method` but its the only way i could get it to function in a basic way. I did try with `class_eval <<-CODE, __FILE__, __LINE__ + 1 ... CODE` and normal `define_method` and neither registered the methods when I checked `News.methods.include?(:most_popular)`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The key here is to use `class_eval` to open up the class you are calling `denormalizable_collection` on.

A simplified example is:

```
class Foo
  def self.make_method(name)
    class_eval do |klass|
      klass.define_singleton_method(name) do
        name
      end 
    end
  end

  make_method(:hello)
end

irb(main):043:0> Foo.hello
=> :hello
```

---

```
module DenormalizableCollection
  def self.included(base)
    base.extend ClassMethods
  end

  module ClassMethods
    def denormalizable_collection(*actions)
      actions.each do |action|
        generate_denormalized_methods(action)
        generate_instance_methods(action)
        generate_callbacks(action)
      end
    end
    private
    def generate_denormalized_methods(action)

      self.class_eval do |klass|
        # you should consider if these should be instance methods instead.
        # define News.most_popular
        define_singleton_method "#{action}" do
          collection = Redis.current.get(send("#{action}_key"))
          return [] unless collection.present?
          JSON.parse(collection).map { |h| DenormalizedHash.new(h) }
        end
        # define News.most_popular
        # define News.set_most_popular
        define_singleton_method "set_#{action}" do
          Redis.current.set(send("#{action}_key"), send("#{action}_data").to_json)
        end
        # define News.most_popular_data, which is a method that returns an array of hashes
        define_singleton_method "#{action}_data" do
          raise NotImplementedError, "#{action}_data is required"
        end
        # define News.most_popular_key, the index key to use inside of redis
        define_singleton_method "#{action}_key" do
          "#{name.underscore}_#{action}".to_sym
        end
      end
    end

    def generate_callbacks(action)
      self.class_eval do
        # Since callbacks call instance methods you have to pass a
        # block if you want to call a class method instead
        after_commit -> { self.class.send("set_#{action}") }
        after_destroy -> { self.class.send("set_#{action}") }
      end
    end

    def generate_instance_methods(action)
      class_eval do
        define_method :a_test_method do
          # ...
        end
      end
    end
  end
end
```

Note here that I'm not using `ActiveSupport::Concern`. Its not that I don't like it. But in this case it adds an additional level of metaprogramming thats enough to make my head explode.

Comment: Thank you! This is exactly what I needed. Can I just ask, when you use `define_singleton_method` is that the only way to define class methods. Someone mentioned that it was like defining the method on the module, rather than on the class itself.

Comment: I cannot seem to define instance methods from within the module. Using `define_method` within `generate_denoramalized_methods` doesn't seem to work but when I manually define with `def testing_method` it does. :-/

Comment: There is an older alternative to define_singleton_method that I can't remember. But it works perfectly fine here if you call in with class eval as the recipient is the class you are calling the  generate_denormalized_methods method in and not the module which defines it. Did you try using define_method in the block?

Comment: I updated the answer with how you would generate instance methods. There was also one problem I didn't realize earlier which is that callbacks call instance methods and not class methods when you pass a symbol. I also managed to screw up the `generate_callbacks` method as it should not have been nested inside `generate_denormalized_methods`.

Comment: Thank you @max. I actually did the same after some playing. Thank you for your help with this, its very much appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried something like:

```rb
  class_methods do
    def denormalizable_collection(*actions)
      actions.each do |action|
        public_send(:after_commit, "send_#{action}")
        ...
      end
    end
  end
```

Comment: This doesn't seem to work unfortunately. I get `NoMethodError: undefined method 'set_most_popular'`.